# How to find the time interval between a PAN gesture in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Im using pan gesture for showing different images.

Pan gesuture is detecting correctly.

The problem is i want to get the time-interval between a pan gesture (in milliseconds).

So how can i fetch the time interval between a pan gesture in iPhone.

i tried in this way but it is not showing correctly.

```
else if([sender state] ==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ) 
    {
        NSLog(@"pan velocity %@ ",[NSDate date]);

        self.previousTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval timeDifference =  [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:previousTime];
        //self.previousTime = currentTime;
        NSLog(@"%f sssss",timeDifference);
    }
```

Can anyone please help me how to find the time interval between a pan gesture in iOS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDate *previousTime = [NSDate date];
double timeDifference = [previousTime timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;
```

*** Edited my post: Of course it's `previousTime`! Sorry.*

Comment: you mean [previousTime timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0;.some confusion in that statement

Comment: This measures the time between the first line and second line, not between subsequent method calls. You would need to do something like `double timeDifference = [self.previousTime timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1000.0; self.previousTime = [NSDate date];`

Comment: I did mean to use the first line to set the time when the first method is called (like self.previousTime = [NSDate date]; in the question) and calculate the time difference by calling the second line from the second method.

Comment: @iDroid usually in which unit the time interval is showing?microseconds or seconds?

Comment: Milliseconds, but you can have it in any unit you'd like by adjusting the factor (1000.0 here)

Comment: "NSTimeInterval is Used to specify a time interval, in seconds." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this (i.e., update `previousTime` after doing the time difference calculation):

```
else if([sender state] ==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ) 
{
    NSLog(@"pan velocity %@ ",[NSDate date]);

    NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference =  [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:previousTime];
    //self.previousTime = currentTime;
    NSLog(@"%f sssss",timeDifference);

    self.previousTime = [NSDate date]; //-- or: self.previousTime = currentTime;

}
```

Comment: @serigio this is giving result like this  0.000003 sssss
 0.000003 sssss
 0.000003 sssss
 0.000002 sssss.

Comment: what is the output of NSLog? would you also try using: `[currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.previousTime]`?